# Рекурсивное создание папок с шансом в 9% на Java

Tags: java, файлы, рекурсия, случайные-числа

Всем доброго времени суток! Стоит интересная задача: на Java нужно написать программу, которая будет создавать рекурсивно по 3 папки (создаются 3 папки, в каждой из них тоже по 3 папки и т.д.) Рекурсия должна остановится с шансом в 9% (то есть есть шанс в 9% что файлы прекратят создаваться). Буду рад любой помощи, всем заранее спасибо и приятного дня :)

Comment: а в чем проблема? рекурсивно создавать папки или посчитать шанс?

Comment: Я не могу понять, как подсчитывать шанс, чтобы рекурсия остановилась. То есть я написал функцию, которая рекурсивно создает эти папки с определенной глубиной (то есть вложенностью). Как дело дошло до рандома, меня заклинило...

Comment: Вы не понимаете, как прервать рекурсию? Можно просто кинуть исключение через `throw`.

Comment: `import java.util.Random;

Random rand = new Random();
int n = rand.nextInt(100);
if (n > 9) {  return;}
тут код создания папок`

Comment: Хорошо, попробую, спасибо

Comment: Можете пожалуйста подсказать, как создавать по 3 папки без указания вложенности? Допустим, создается в папке 3 папки, как мне вернуться на папку выше и создать 3 папки уже во второй. Например, создались папки 1, 2 и 3. В папке 1 создались еще 1, 2 и 3. Как вернуться на папку выше, чтобы и в папке 2 создались папки 1, 2 и 3? Я совсем запутался...

Comment: Вам не нужно "возвращаться. Просто сделайте правильно рекурсию. и все

Comment: Можете помочь с этим пожалуйста? Уже неделю думаю над этим и не пойму, как правильно сконструировать код

Comment: показывайте то, что у Вас есть сейчас, а мы посмотрим, покритикуем. Я то могу написать код за Вас, но какой в этом смысл?